# Indexing issues while partitioning with dbms_redefinition

Tags: partitioning, oracle-11g

I get an error while doing the redefinition. Following are the steps which I have taken so far:

#### Step 1. Start redefinition

```
DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE(v_name, 'T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT',
 dbms_redefinition.CONS_USE_ROWID);
```

Successful

#### Step 2. Creating a interim table

```
CREATE TABLE "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT_ONLINE" 
(   "SERIAL_ID" NUMBER(15,0), 
"CONTEXTID" NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ENTITYNAME" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ENTITYCOMPONENT" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
"SOLUTIONTYPE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"JOBTIMESTAMP" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"EAJOBNAME" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
"PRJOBNAME" VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
"FAJOBNAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
"STEPNAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
"LOTNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"LOTTYPE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"CARRIERNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"PRODUCTNAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
"RECIPENAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
"WAFERID" VARCHAR2(23 BYTE), 
"MATERIALNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"MATERIALCOUNT" NUMBER(4,0), 
"CAPACITY" NUMBER(4,0), 
"TECHNOLOGY" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
"RETICLE" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE), 
"LAYER" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"SWRLOT" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
"PORTNAME" NUMBER(1,0), 
"SLOT" NUMBER(3,0), 
"RUNNUMBER" NUMBER(2,0), 
"MVINTIME" DATE, 
"ROUTE" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
"EPA" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
"PROCTIME" DATE, 
"IMAGEID" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
"PRODUCTGROUP" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
"BASICTYPE" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
"PRETOOL" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
"REWORK" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"SENDAHEAD" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"SEQUENCE" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
"RSN" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
"COMPLETED" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0, 
"LAYER2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"RETICLE2" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE), 
"TRUSTED_FLAG" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE), 
"VALID_FLAG" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
"RECIPE" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
"POSITIONTYPE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
"PROCESS_TYPE" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
"IN_WORK" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0, 
"D_CARRIERNAME" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
"SUMOSTEP" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
"INSERTED_TIME" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, 
 PRIMARY KEY ("SERIAL_ID"))
PARTITION BY RANGE ("INSERTED_TIME")
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(PARTITION "p1_1"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2012-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')))
```

Successful

#### Step 3. Starting the redefinition

```
DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE (uname => v_name, 
  orig_table => 'T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT', 
  int_table => 'T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT_ONLINE',
  col_mapping => '', options_flag => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);
```

Successful

#### Step 4. Copying the dependents

```
DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(v_name, 'T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT',
  'T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT_ONLINE', 
  dbms_redefinition.cons_orig_params,
  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, error_count);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('errors := ' || TO_CHAR(error_count));
```

#### Error:

```
ORA-01408: such column list already indexed.
```

I have following indexes on my existing column.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CDS_USER"."SYS_C0012094" ON "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT" ("SERIAL_ID")
CREATE INDEX "CDS_USER"."I_FDC_CONTEXTID" ON "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT" ("CONTEXTID") 
CREATE INDEX "CDS_USER"."I_FDC_ENTITY" ON "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT" ("ENTITYNAME")
CREATE INDEX "CDS_USER"."I_FDC_TIMESTAMP"ON"CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT"("JOBTIMESTAMP") 
CREATE INDEX "CDS_USER"."I_FDC_CTRL" ON "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT" ("EAJOBNAME") 
CREATE INDEX "CDS_USER"."I_FDC_PRJ" ON "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT" ("PRJOBNAME")
CREATE INDEX "CDS_USER"."I_FDC_CARRIER" ON "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT" ("CARRIERNAME")
CREATE INDEX "CDS_USER"."I_FDC_MATERIAL" ON "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT" ("MATERIALNAME") 
CREATE INDEX "CDS_USER"."I_FDC_PORT" ON "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT" ("PORTNAME")
CREATE INDEX "CDS_USER"."I_FDC_SLOT" ON "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT" ("SLOT")
CREATE INDEX "CDS_USER"."I_FDC_ENTITY_LOT" ON "CDS_USER"."T_FDC_TOOLCONTEXT" ("ENTITYNAME", "LOTNAME")
```

What can I do to avoid the error?

Comment: You'll need to edit the question with the exact steps you've taken so far. There's not enough information to use in order to help you.

Comment: Having said that, I think it'll be the PK on the new table. What does `select * from dba_redefinition_errors;` say?

Comment: I have posted the question again. Please see. Thanks

Comment: If you observe the index 3 and index 10, both of them have one column in common. Is it causing the problem. But how is that existing in the original column?

Comment: The create table statement sets serial_id as pk, which will create an index. This will make statement 1 fail.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, minimal test case that reproduces the error, showing it's the intermediate table PK that is the problem:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE SO33070_ORIGINAL
  2  (
  3          SERIAL_ID NUMBER(15,0),
  4      INSERTED_TIME DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  5          PRIMARY KEY (SERIAL_ID)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE SO33070_NEW
  2  (
  3          SERIAL_ID NUMBER(15,0),
  4      INSERTED_TIME DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  5          PRIMARY KEY (SERIAL_ID)
  6  )
  7  PARTITION BY RANGE ("INSERTED_TIME") INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
  8  (
  9    PARTITION "p1_1" VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2012-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
 10  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> exec DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE( uname => 'PHIL', orig_table => 'SO33070_ORIGINAL', int_table => 'SO33070_NEW', col_mapping => '', options_flag => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2  num_errors NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4
  5  DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(uname => 'PHIL', orig_table=>'SO33070_ORIGINAL', int_table=>'SO33070_NEW', copy_indexes=>dbms_redefinition.cons_orig_params , copy_triggers=>TRUE, copy_constraints=>TRUE, copy_privileges=>TRUE, ignore_errors=>FALSE, num_errors=>num_errors, copy_statistics=>false);
  6
  7  END;
  8  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01408: such column list already indexed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 1364
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 2026
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL>
SQL> col object_owner for a6
SQL> col base_table_name for a20
SQL> col ddl_txt for a55
SQL>
SQL> select object_type, object_owner, base_table_name, ddl_txt
  2  from dba_redefinition_errors;

OBJECT_TYPE  OBJECT BASE_TABLE_NAME
------------ ------ --------------------
DDL_TXT
-------------------------------------------------------
INDEX        PHIL   SO33070_ORIGINAL
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PHIL"."TMP$$_SYS_C00110330" ON "PH
IL"."SO33070_NEW" ("SERIA


SQL>
SQL> exec DBMS_REDEFINITION.ABORT_REDEF_TABLE(uname=>'PHIL', orig_table=>'SO33070_ORIGINAL', int_table=>'SO33070_NEW');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

You have 2 options to fix this.

Option 1 - create the intermediate table without a primary key (**best option!!**):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE SO33070_ORIGINAL
  2  (
  3          SERIAL_ID NUMBER(15,0),
  4      INSERTED_TIME DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  5          PRIMARY KEY (SERIAL_ID)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE SO33070_NEW
  2  (
  3          SERIAL_ID NUMBER(15,0),
  4      INSERTED_TIME DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
  5  )
  6  PARTITION BY RANGE ("INSERTED_TIME") INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
  7  (
  8    PARTITION "p1_1" VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2012-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> exec DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE( uname => 'PHIL', orig_table => 'SO33070_ORIGINAL', int_table => 'SO33070_NEW', col_mapping => '', options_flag => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2  num_errors NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4
  5  DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(uname => 'PHIL', orig_table=>'SO33070_ORIGINAL', int_table=>'SO33070_NEW', copy_indexes=>dbms_redefinition.cons_orig_params , copy_triggers=>TRUE, copy_constraints=>TRUE, copy_privileges=>TRUE, ignore_errors=>TRUE, num_errors=>num_errors, copy_statistics=>false);
  6
  7  END;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> col object_owner for a6
SQL> col base_table_name for a20
SQL> col ddl_txt for a55
SQL>
SQL> select object_type, object_owner, base_table_name, ddl_txt
  2  from dba_redefinition_errors;

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL> exec DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE(uname=>'PHIL', orig_table=>'SO33070_ORIGINAL', int_table=>'SO33070_NEW');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Option 2 - simply tell `DBMS_REDEFINITION` to ignore the error (`ignore_errors=>true`).

It looks like there are some errors, but they don't matter as the PK constraint and index was created when the intermediate table was created:

```
SQL> exec DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE( uname => 'PHIL', orig_table => 'SO33070_ORIGINAL', int_table => 'SO33070_NEW', col_mapping => '', options_flag => DBMS_REDEFINITION.CONS_USE_ROWID);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2  num_errors NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4
  5  DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(uname => 'PHIL', orig_table=>'SO33070_ORIGINAL', int_table=>'SO33070_NEW', copy_indexes=>dbms_redefinition.cons_orig_params , copy_triggers=>TRUE, copy_constraints=>TRUE, copy_privileges=>TRUE, ignore_errors=>TRUE, num_errors=>num_errors, copy_statistics=>false);
  6
  7  END;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> col object_owner for a6
SQL> col base_table_name for a20
SQL> col ddl_txt for a55
SQL>
SQL> select object_type, object_owner, base_table_name, ddl_txt
  2  from dba_redefinition_errors;

OBJECT_TYPE  OBJECT BASE_TABLE_NAME
------------ ------ --------------------
DDL_TXT
-------------------------------------------------------
INDEX        PHIL   SO33070_ORIGINAL
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PHIL"."TMP$$_SYS_C00110410" ON "PH
IL"."SO33070_NEW" ("SERIA

CONSTRAINT   PHIL   SO33070_ORIGINAL
ALTER TABLE "PHIL"."SO33070_NEW" ADD CONSTRAINT "TMP$$_
SYS_C00110410" PRIMARY KE


SQL>
SQL> exec DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE(uname=>'PHIL', orig_table=>'SO33070_ORIGINAL', int_table=>'SO33070_NEW');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. You solved a big problem for me. Just one more question, If I don't create the primary key, will it not be a problem?As I my original table has this primary key. will this primary key be automatically created during redefinition?

Comment: Yes, it will. Run my test cases yourself and you can see for yourself.